# How to read input elements to an array in fortran 77

Tags: fortran

I have a main function which creates an array and passes the array to a subroutine, the subroutine should then read in values to the array, my array has a size of 5 so the subroutine should have 5 numbers input into the array.

Here is my code currently:

```
    program main
    real arr(5)
    
c
    call readData(arr)
    stop
    end

    subroutine readData(arr)
c
    do i=1, 5
        read (*,*) arr(i)
    end do

    return 
    end
```

Comment: You **must** use `implicit none` in both units. In the program and in the subroutine. You should also always post your error messages.

Comment: Note the above is at least fortran90, it does not conform to the long deleted fortran77 standard (which should not be used any more)

Comment: For `arr` to be an array in `readData` you need to declare it as an array. As it is, you've told the compiler it's a function.

Comment: See point 1. in the answer to the linked question.